# Create Gravity Forms entry programmatically with add_entry() but still call usual hooks

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I'm using add_entry to create form submissions in PHP.  The [documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#add-entry) states:

"The usual hooks that are triggered while saving entries are not fired here."

However, I need to integrate it with add-ons that trigger events when entries are created, as well as send email notifications.  I've found some tutorials on how to send notifications, but I need more than that.  Is there a process for creating the entry that triggers all the usual hooks, as if the user submitted it themselves?

Answer (score 3):

I immediately discovered my problem.  Instead of using add_entry(), I should be using submit_form()

https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#submit-form